# Mac open new terminal Window and execute command

Tags: macos, terminal, ffmpeg

I am trying to get this script to run, I can't correctly pass the command to the new terminal window.

The script takes one argument, a video file, it then prompts the user to select a video size to output. From there i would like it to open a new terminal window and execute the ffmpeg command.

```
#!/bin/sh

input=$1
CD="CocoaDialog.app/Contents/MacOS/CocoaDialog"

# Get width from user
width=`$CD standard-inputbox --title "Please Enter Video Width" | sed -n '1!p'`
proceed=`$CD ok-msgbox --text "You entered $width press ok to proceed"`

if [ $proceed == 1 ]
then
  # Build MP4 video creation command
  cmd_to_run="./ffmpeg -i \""$input"\" -vf scale=$width:-1 -strict -2 -c:a aac -b:a 256k -b:v 4096k -vcodec libx264 -crf 22 -preset slow -threads 0 \""${input%.*}.converted.$width.mp4"\""

  # Execute command in new terminal window
  osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"$cmd_to_run\""
else
    echo "You selected cancel..."
fi
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your command's variable substitutions in single quotes:

```
input="/path/too/foo bar.mp4"
cmd_to_run="./ffmpeg -i '$input' …
osascript -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"$cmd_to_run\""
```

Otherwise the parameter will be substituted too early.